# This Excel VBA code is not working. I need to update the named ranges in Formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have worksheets named as Wk1,Wk2 Wk3 etc.

All the named ranges on each sheet have names that start with the name of the Sheet. e.g on Wk1 sheet I have a named range called Wk1TotalWeight.

i have formulas that reference these named ranges on each sheet.e.g =Wk1TotalWeight*2

Whenever I add a new worksheet with a name starting with Wk I want the named ranges in the formulas on that sheet to update so that they start with the name of their parent sheet. eg if a formaula is =Wk1TotalWeight*2 on sheet Wk2 I want the formula to update to =Wk2TotalWeight*2

i tried this code but it is not working.

```
Sub ChangeWkNamesInFormulasOnNewWksheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "Wk", 1) > 0 Then
            For Each r In ws.Range("C118:I119")
                r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", r.Parent.Name)
            Next r

            For Each r In ws.Range("C166:J170")
                r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", r.Parent.Name)
            Next r


        End If
    Next ws

    MsgBox "Done"
    End Sub
```

Comment: This works for me. Are you sure that the string "Wk1" can be found in C166:J170?

Comment: "Whenever I add a new worksheet". This might be a silly suggestion, but did you run the code from the editor?

Comment: Heres what i was doing  wrong. I had sheets Wk1,Wk2 and Wk3 and then added a Wk4 sheet. I copied the formulas from the Wk3 sheet to Wk4 but I shoild have copied the formulas from Wk1 to Wk4. Because i copied from Wk3 to Wk4 the formulas contained nmaed ranges starting with Wk3. That is why the MAcro did not work. Thanks noumenal for making me think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres what i was doing wrong.

I had sheets Wk1,Wk2 and Wk3 and then added a Wk4 sheet.

I copied the formulas from the Wk3 sheet to Wk4 but I should have copied the formulas from Wk1 to Wk4.

Because I copied from Wk3 to Wk4 the formulas contained named ranges starting with Wk3. In other words the string "Wk1" was not present in the ranges. These named ranges needed to be starting with Wk1 in order for the code to work

That is why the code did not work. Thanks to noumenal in the comments in the above post

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use simply `r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, "Wk1", ws.Name)`

Comment: Ill try this later and see does it work. See the comments in the above post for what i was doing wrong